# What is the purpose of the -e flag in this script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I got a script from - http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-conditional-expression/

It is -

```
$ cat exist.sh
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
if [ -e $file ]
then
    echo -e "File $file exists"
else
    echo -e "File $file doesnt exists"
fi

$ ./exist.sh /usr/bin/boot.ini
File /usr/bin/boot.ini exists
```

I used the same code without -e near both the echo and it works. So, what is the purpose of using -e there ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet? That should always be your first action.

Comment: -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-e` flag enables interpretation of the following backslash-escaped
     characters in each STRING:

```
\a          alert (bell)

\b          backspace

\c          suppress trailing newline

\e          escape 

\f          form feed

\n          new line

\r          carriage return

\t          horizontal tab

\v          vertical tab

\\          backslash

\NNN
      the character whose ASCII code is NNN (octal); if NNN is not
      a valid octal number, it is printed literally.

\xnnn
      the character whose ASCII code is the hexadecimal value 
      nnn (one to three digits)
```

Source: http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html

Answer (score 1):

`-e` enables interpretation of backslash escapes, but answering your question, about the  purpose of it being there, it seems to be none at all. It can even be harmful. `echo -e` is useful if you want to include those backslashed characters in the string, but that is not the case in your example, unless `$file` has them, and then this can happen:

```
$ touch test\\test
$ ls
exist.sh  test\test
$ ./exist.sh test\\test
File test   est exists
```

Without the `-e` you get the correct file name. Of course, this is all academic because it's unlikely that files will contain backslashed entities, but then we can conclude those switches were put there with the express goal of confusing you.